# Partial serialization with DataContractJsonSerializer

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization

I have the following class used in a legacy WCF service

```
[MessageContract()]
public class Document
{
    [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
    public MetaData Data { get; set; }

    [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [MessageBodyMember(Order = 1)]
    public Stream File { get; set; }
}
```

This is passed so a method called `AddDocument` to push the document into a store.

At some point in the past I added logging on all our services through a Castle.Windsor interceptor which serialized the data passed to keep a trace of what's passed to the service.

```
public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
{
    Logger.Debug(() =>
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(1000);
        sb.AppendFormat("{2} -> {0}.{1}(", invocation.TargetType.Name, invocation.Method.Name, SomeCode);
        sb.Append(string.Join(", ", invocation.Arguments.Select(a => a == null ? "null" : DumpObject(a)).ToArray()));
        sb.Append(")");
        return sb.ToString();
    });

    invocation.Proceed();

    Logger.Debug(() =>
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(1000);
        sb.AppendFormat("OUT {0}", invocation.ReturnValue != null ? DumpObject(invocation.ReturnValue) : "void");
        return sb.ToString();
    });
}
```

with the serialization in `DumpObject` using the `DataContractJsonSerializer`

```
private string DumpObject(object argument)
{
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        try
        {
            var ser = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer(argument.GetType());
            ser.WriteObject(ms, argument);
            return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, Convert.ToInt32(ms.Length));
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return "NA";
        }
    }
}
```

I never was able to serialize the `Document` class because it contains a `Stream`, and the argument always was serialized as 'NA'. However I would like to know if it is possible to serialize the rest of the object without the stream.

I thought about changing the object type just for serialization, for example by mapping it to another object with a subset of the original object, but this solution doesn't please me since I'm checking and swapping a lot of data for an operation that should be very low key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by implementing the `IDataContactSurrogate` and providing it to the `DataContractJsonSerializer`.

```
var settings = new DataContractJsonSerializerSettings() { DataContractSurrogate = new SkipStreamSurrogate()};
var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(argument.GetType(), settings);

serializer.WriteObject(ms, argument);
```

Implementation:

```
public sealed class SkipStreamSurrogate : IDataContractSurrogate
{
    public object GetCustomDataToExport(Type clrType, Type dataContractType)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public object GetCustomDataToExport(MemberInfo memberInfo, Type dataContractType)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public Type GetDataContractType(Type type)
    {
        return type;
    }

    public object GetDeserializedObject(object obj, Type targetType)
    {
        return obj;
    }

    public void GetKnownCustomDataTypes(Collection<Type> customDataTypes)
    {
    }

    public object GetObjectToSerialize(object obj, Type targetType)
    {
        // Skip serialization of a System.Stream
        if (obj is Stream)
        { return null; }

        return obj;
    }

    public Type GetReferencedTypeOnImport(string typeName, string typeNamespace, object customData)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public CodeTypeDeclaration ProcessImportedType(CodeTypeDeclaration typeDeclaration, CodeCompileUnit compileUnit)
    {
        return typeDeclaration;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's great! However I had a strange problem, which is that I couldn't find the [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) that you used. Well, I used another one and it works

Comment: This is a new constructor in .Net 4.5 ([link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194418(v=vs.110).aspx)).